# Saxon - can we query if it's using a schema

Tags: saxon

Is there a way to query if the loaded data in Saxon has a schema file that has been applied to the data? I'm asking because if it's no schema, then we can parse returned strings and if they match the format for the xml standard for datetime, convert them at a low level in our library.

For example, if the underlying data is always String, Number, or Boolean (JSON, XML with no schema), then we look at each returned string value and if it's in the form "2002-05-30T09:00:00" we parse it and turn it into an OffsetDateTime. But only if there's no schema as a schema returning that as a String supposedly has its reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tell whether a node has been processed using a schema by testing its type: without a schema, element nodes will always be of type `element(*, xs:untyped)`, and the "typed value" of attribute nodes (result of the data() function) will be `xs:untypedAtomic` rather than (say) `xs:string`.

Nodes are the only thing you can apply a schema to: if it's not a node, then no schema has been applied to it.

I don't think I fully understand your problem, but on the surface, it looks as if the distinction you are looking for might be the distinction between `xs:untypedAtomic` and `xs:string`. But only if the things you call "underlying data" and "returned strings" (whatever those are) are careful to retain this distinction.